# Cursor 's stuck on the right side of the screen when using Wacom tablet

Tags: resolution, cursor, wacom, graphics-tablet

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 x64. When I move the cursor off the screen on the right side of the screen using my pen-tablet (as mouse), there is no way to move it back again. The only way is to  a mouse and move to the left. Other sides of the screen are not affected by this. When the cursor is lost on the left, the keyboard is also not responding.

Please note that the info below shows monitor DFP2 has a resolution of 1920x1200, but the stylus area is 5104x3712. Using '$ xsetwacom --set "Wacom Bamboo1 stylus" MapToOuput DFP2' or '$ xsetwacom --set "Wacom Bamboo1 stylus ResetArea"' set back the area to 5104x3712. Adjusting it manually to 1920x1200 will make the cursor disappear/unusable.

Is there any way to fix this?

```
$ fglrxinfo
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Radeon HD 4870 X2 
OpenGL version string: 3.3.11399 Compatibility Profile Context

display: :0  screen: 1
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Radeon HD 4870 X2 
OpenGL version string: 3.3.11399 Compatibility Profile Context

$ xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Bamboo1 stylus                      id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Comfort Optical Mouse 1000      id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Bamboo1 eraser                      id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Bamboo1 cursor                      id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard            id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard            id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]


$ xsetwacom --list devices
Wacom Bamboo1 stylus                id: 8   type: STYLUS    
Wacom Bamboo1 eraser                id: 12  type: ERASER    
Wacom Bamboo1 cursor                id: 13  type: CURSOR    

$ xsetwacom --version
0.11.0

$ xsetwacom --get "Wacom Bamboo1 stylus" all
Option "Area" "0 0 5104 3712"
'Button' requires exactly 1 value(s).
Option "ToolDebugLevel" "0"
Option "TabletDebugLevel" "0"
Option "Suppress" "2"
Option "RawSample" "4"
Option "PressureCurve" "0 0 100 100"
Option "Mode" "Absolute"
Option "TabletPCButton" "on"
Option "Touch" "on"
Option "Gesture" "off"
Option "ZoomDistance" "50"
Option "ScrollDistance" "20"
Option "TapTime" "250"
Option "Capacity" "-1"
Property 'Wacom Proximity Threshold' does not exist on device.
Option "Rotate" "none"
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Strip Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Strip Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Strip Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Strip Buttons' does not exist on device.
Option "Threshold" "27"
Option "ToolID" ""
Option "ToolSerial" ""
Option "TabletID" ""

$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1200, maximum 1920 x 1920
DFP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DFP2 connected 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200      60.0*+
   1920x1080      60.0 +
   1680x1050      60.0 +
   1440x900       59.9 +
   1280x800       60.0 +
   1152x648       60.0 +
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1600x900       60.0  
   1360x1024      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1280x768       59.9  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   720x480        60.0  
   640x480        60.0  
CRT1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
CRT2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
TV disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
CV disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Do you mean using Wacom pen-tablet as an input device like mouse?

Comment: Yes, I use a wacom bamboo pen tablet as mouse input device.

Comment: Started a Live CD of Ubuntu 11.10 x32, and I dont have the issue over there.

Comment: I recommend posting an answer to your own question.

Comment: Thanks for you help... Where do you suggest I begin?

Comment: Right at the bottom of the page, type about what you've tried and that the issue get solved and post it. Thank you.

Comment: JJB3 are you saying this is a 32-bit/64-bit issue? Does it work on precise live cd?

Comment: OK, burned x64 CD and did not had the issue over there. Any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like you somehow edited the configuration or otherwise changed some settings that caused the issue. I suggest following the answer given, but first purging all the config files you have around wacom. I don't have any quick and dirty answer on how to do this.. You can use apt-get purge to remove and clean up bad configs.

Comment: apt-get purged the wacom-dkms and xserver-xorg-input-wacom, rebooted, still same issue... Then ran modprobe -r wacom (hoping this would remove the driver). Then rebooted, installed wacom-dkms and xserver-xorg-input-wacom, and the issue is back...

Answer (score 2):

I have a Bamboo Connect, latest version. In order to get it working I needed a new wacom driver 0.12.x. I had been using 0.12.0 compiled from source code which required a new compile with every kernel update. I checked and saw a newer 0.12.1 was available from the launchpad via a PPA. I installed it by adding the PPA with Software Sources, Other Software tab and the Add... button. The following line is entered as the "APT line:" followed by the Add Source button.

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/lekensteyn/wacom-tablet/ubuntu oneiric main
```

I then ran the Update Manager and clicked the Check button to insure the new PPA was available for install.

I then ran the Software Center, searched for wacom, clicked Show technical items and installed the package wacom-dkms

Last I did a restart to run with the new driver.

Since I have a newer Wacom Bamboo I can't certify that this will solve your problem but it works correctly with mine.

Comment: I added the PPA > updated > and rebooted, but the issue still remains. Cannot find the wacom-dkms by the way, but some other wacom package were updated by this PPA.

Comment: Run Software Center and enter wacom-dkms into the search field. Installing it installs the new driver. There will be no executable package name wacom-dkms. wacom-dkms only exists as a .deb package.

Comment: OK installed wacom-dkms, rebooted, but no effect.

Comment: I'm afraid I have no additional suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I just had a similar problem but with a laptop and only one display installed.  This thread got me thinking how to fix it.

**Cause:**  Turns out that my system had autodetected the alternate display outputs, which I was not using, and had enabled a second display.  I was rolling right off my display into a ghost display on the right.

**Solution:**  I turned off the second display in settings and the problem went away.  Of course, I'll probably have to enable it again when I plug my HDMI TV in to watch a movie but no big deal there.

Answer (score 0):

I did a clean install of ubuntu 12.04 x64, and the issue is gone now.

Comment: I checked and most values are still the same, these are changed;

$ fglrxinfo
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Radeon HD 4870 X2
OpenGL version string: 3.3.11627 Compatibility Profile Context


$ xsetwacom --version
0.14.0